# Animating left offset doesnt work on safari

Tags: css, animation, safari, css-animations

I have some text that I want to animate with a typewriter animation:

```html
<h2 id="slogan">we make the web.</h2>
```

It has some simple css to animate its transform in steps, and has a `::before` psuedo element to show the letters one by one, also with a stepped animation.

```css
animation: type 2s steps(16) forwards 2200ms;
```

```css
@keyframes type
{
    to { left: 100%; }
}
```

This works exactly as intended on chromium based browsers, and firefox. But it doesn't animate properly on safari, it looks like it jumps in 2 steps instead of 16.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hy6T.jpg) is a working and non-working video example.

---

**This was tested on:**

Microsoft Edge 91.0.864.48 (working)

Google Chrome 91.0.4472.106 (working)

Firefox 88.0.1 (working)

Safari 15.0 (17612.1.15.1.14) (NOT working) - tested on the first dev beta of macOS Monterey

Safari iOS (NOT working) - tested on the first dev beta of iOS 15

---

I am open to the idea that this issue might be because of the beta software, and would therefore want other devs to test on different versions of safari and share the results.

If you know what causes this, I would really appreciate you taking the time to explain the matter.

All help is welcome, and thank you for your time.

Comment: Hey Martin, your approach is perfectly valid.
It appears to be a regression introduced with Safari 15. Interestingly I was only able to reproduce this on iOS Safari while Mac OS Safari 15.0 seems to work just fine.
Have you tried filing a bug [here](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/)?

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too, seems iOS 15.1 resolved it, but you could try to replace the animation with transform.

```
@keyframes type {
   0% {
     transform: translateX(0);
   }
   100% {
     transform: translateX(-100%);
   }
}
```